# Why mysql use only one index for table?

Tags: mysql

Index merge is used very seldom and often is not efficient.

But search engines like `Elastic`, `Sphinx` can use few indexes efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Either "index merge" is inefficient that most other techniques because of what it has to do:

1. Gather `PRIMARY KEYs` based on one index.
2. Gather `PRIMARY KEYs` based on the other index.
3. Sort each list
4. Merge the lists
5. Look up the desired rows based on the PKs
6. Then move on to whatever else is going on.

Furthermore, "Index merge intersect" is almost always less efficient than a composite index that combines the columns being searched on.  See my discussion here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1

Comment: But why few indexes in `Elastic`, `Sphinx` are efficient?